# How can I increase an image's opacity in the video editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I rendered some video effects that I want to overlay on top of some video footage in the video editor. The video effects are imported as an image sequence.

Turns out the video effects are too transparent. I can duplicate the image sequence and stack them to increase the opacity, but is there a better way? I tried the curve strip modifier but it can only adjust RGB.

Here is a screenshot of my current setup (edited to remove personal info), all the clips are in "Alpha Over" mode.

[image: Blender screenshot of clip stack]

Comment: can you show us how you "overlayed" them in a screenshot? with settings?

Comment: @Chris, ok, I just added a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your alpha-Image.

[image]

Increase saturation and multipy.

Before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: Ok that seems to work, thank you. Is it equivalent to the image stacking I was doing before?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean with equivalent, but I think it is a very similar effect.

Comment: I guess I'm asking is "mathematically", does changing the multiple/saturation have the same result as stacking images

Comment: Honestly - i don't know.